# Can I use OCR readers on web pages?

Tags: python, ocr

If its possible thanks!

My code:

```py
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = Image.open('https://gefefjwefwefjyweftwf.com')
text = tess.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Is there a way to do it??

Comment: you can use webscrapping to get data from website if you want to run ocr on webpage images you can download images from website using urllib and then run ocr on that

Comment: ok I'll check..